# Variation of Division Algorithm

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

How to derive this version of the division algorithm .

For integers a, b with b ≠ 0 there exist unique integers q and r that satisfy a = qb + r, where -1/2|b| < r ≤ 1/2 b.

I started off with letting a = q'b + r', where 0≤ r' < |b|. When 0 ≤ r' ≤ 0.5 b, let r = r' and q = q'; when 0.5 |b| < r' < |b|, let r = r' - |b| and q = q' +1 if b> 0 or q = q' -1 if b < 0. 
Then the working gets messy. Can someone tell me how to continue?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. If $\frac{|b|}{2}=|b|-\frac{|b|}{2}<r<|b|,$ let $r':=r-|b|$ and let $q':=q+\frac{|b|}{b}.$ Then $$a=bq'+r',$$ and $-\dfrac{|b|}{2}<r'<0<\dfrac{|b|}{2}.$

Note that it doesn't matter if $b<0$ or $b>0.$ The uniqueness part is easy.

Answer (score 0):

By ordinary division, for given $a,b$, there exist unique integers $q,r$ satisfying $a+\lfloor\dfrac b2\rfloor=qb+r$ with $0\le r<b$.

Then, there exist unique integers $q,r':=r-\lfloor\dfrac b2\rfloor$ satisfying $a=qb+r'$ with $-\lfloor\dfrac b2\rfloor\le r'<b-\lfloor\dfrac b2\rfloor$.